# Variable substitution in terraform built-in functions

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

In Terraform, I do not manage to assign a private IP to my instances using the *cidrhost* built-in function.
I'm pretty sure I do not have the correct syntax but cannot figure out what is wrong.

```
# Get the list of subnet ids of my VPC
data "aws_subnet_ids" "org_subnet_ids" {
    vpc_id = "${data.aws_vpc.org_vpc.id}"
}

# Get the list of subnets from the ids
data "aws_subnet" "org_subnets" {
    count = "${length(data.aws_subnet_ids.org_subnet_ids.ids)}"
    id = "${data.aws_subnet_ids.org_subnet_ids.ids[count.index]}"
}

# Create instances and assign each of them to a different subnet
resource "aws_instance" "manager" {
  count                  = 3
  ami                    = "${data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id}"
  instance_type          = "t2.small"
  subnet_id              = "${data.aws_subnet_ids.org_subnet_ids.ids[count.index]}"
  private_ip             = "${cidrhost(${data.aws_subnet.org_subnets.cidr_block[count.index]}, count.index + 1)}"
  tags {
      Name = "manager-${count.index + 1}"
  }
}
```

"$ terraform plan" fails with the following error:

```
 Error: Failed to load root config module: Error loading ./provisionning/aws/ec2.tf
Error reading config for aws_instance[manager]: parse error at 1:12: expected expression but found invalid sequence "$"
```

Any idea what I'm missing here ?

Comment: You don't need the nested `${}`. So you should be fine with `"${cidrhost(data.aws_subnet.org_subnets.cidr_block[count.index], count.index + 1)}"`

Comment: Thanks. It seems to go one step further but I have the following error for each of the instance: "aws_instance.manager[1]: Resource 'data.aws_subnet.org_subnets' not found for variable 'data.aws_subnet.org_subnets.cidr_block'". Strange as the data is defined but above.

Comment: I didn't look closely enough at that apparently because your index is in the wrong place too: `"${cidrhost(data.aws_subnet.org_subnets[count.ind‌​ex].cidr_block, count.index + 1)}"`

Comment: it does not seem to like it: Error reading config for aws_instance[manager]: parse error at 1:54: expected ")" but found ".". I'm not yet that familiar with built-in function, should I use some kind of lookup to get the cidr_block or should it be available directly with the dot notation ?

Comment: Using the element() built-in function fixed the thing :) "${cidrhost(element(data.aws_subnet.org_subnets.*.cidr_block, count.index), count.index + 1)}". Thanks a lot for your help. There were several errors in my approach then  :)